# How to add Kafka Consumer JMX metrics to Application Insights?

Tags: jmx, azure-application-insights, azure-monitoring

We are trying to send Kafka metrics to App Insights by using the JMX section of the config.  E.g. like below.  Note that this does work for other non-Kafka JMX metrics.

```
azure:
  application-insights:
    instrumentation-key: x-y-z
    jmx:
      jmx-counters[0]: kafka.consumer:type=consumer-fetch-manager-metrics/.*fetch-rate/Kafka Fetch Rate
      jmx-counters[1]: kafka.consumer:type=consumer-fetch-manager-metrics,client-id=([-.w]+)/fetch-rate/Kafka Fetch Rate 2
```

The issue we are having is that the Kafka JMX metrics also contain the Kafka Client ID which is dynamic, containing a timestamp which changes each time the app is restarted.  See the screenshot of JConsole below (prefix of Client ID has been blanked out).

[image]

It is possible to do this kind of monitoring with Promethues using the JMX Exporter with config like below.  Is it possible to do this with Azure Applications Insights and if so how?

```
  - pattern: kafka.consumer<type=consumer-fetch-manager-metrics, client-id=(.+)><>(records-lag-max)
    name: kafka_consumer-fetch-manager-metrics_$2
    labels:
      client-id: $1
```

Comment: Did you find a way?

Comment: No.  If I remember correctly Microsoft came back to us internally saying they would consider making this a change on their backlog.  And then we moved on.